# What is the best way to store data when I have 50.000 unique words?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have to find(to check for presense) and remove words(if required word exists then delete it) quickly in android app. I recieve words from user. I store data in `HashMap<String, Integer>`, where String - unique word, Integer - some number. I check presense required word in hashMap using `hashMap.containsKey(word)` (I hope it occurs for O(1), computing only hash code). If required word exists in hashMap then I have to remove element from hashMap using this word as key `hashMap.remove(word)`, so I store all words as keys. What is an optimal way?

```
public void fillMap() {
    try {
        String str = "";
        int i = 0;
        while ((str = stream.readLine()) != null) {
            hashMap.put(str, i);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "FileNotFoundException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void checkWord() {
    String word = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
    if (hashMap.containsKey(word)) {
        hashMap.remove(word);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Click "edit" to edit your post and add some code that you have written. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: "What is an optimal way?" What do you need to optimize for? Incidentally, I strongly doubt that you need an optimal way, but rather you need a *sufficient* way, i.e. something "good enough". In either case, it is *your* requirements which define the criteria for choosing one solution over another.

Comment: 50k words is pretty small, `HashMap` is likely fine. If you know that your map contains no null values, or you don't actually need the value for the removed key, you can skip the `contains` check and just call `hashMap.remove(word)` unconditionally.

Comment: I have to show "ok" when word is existed and remove it then. If I call straight `hashMap.remove(word)` I will not know word is existed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

50k words is pretty small, HashMap is likely fine. Only you can say whether it actually is an acceptable solution, since you know your requirements.

Whenever you ask "is this optimal", you need to specify what optimality means for you: minimal space, minimal run time, maximal readability of the code etc. With many of these, optimality isn't actually required: you just need something which is *sufficient* to meet your requirements, e.g. doesn't use more than X space, doesn't take longer than Y to run.

One minor point is that you can make removal more efficient by not checking `hashMap.containsKey` first:

```
if (hashMap.remove(word) != null) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

which simply avoids looking up the value in the map twice. Note that this only works because you are inserting non-null values into the map when you construct it.

Comment: Yes you are right, I actually could avoid `hashMap.containsKey(word)` in my case, thanks. When I say "an optimal way" I mean minimal space and minimal run time. I did not write, it's my fault. Don't you know hashMap.remove is computing for complication  O(1) or O(n)?

Comment: You can't have two criteria for optimality: you can consider many parameters, but you need some single-valued function of these parameters to optimize. Consider two implementations: one is slow but uses minimal memory; the other is blisteringly fast but requires an enormous amount of memory. How do you choose between them? What is the balance of space and run time you are willing to accept?